# Как достать текст с экрана эмулятора?

Tags: android-studio

Имеется Android приложение.

Как из эмулятора Android Studio получить текст, отображённый на экране?

Comment: про книги, форматы, шифрование, погоду на марсе, глубину пропасти между жизнью и смертью, и тому подобное, — всё это абсолютно лишняя лирика, не имеющая к собственно вопросу никакого отношения. без неё вопрос вполне годный. вношу правку.